# Retrieve a V2 item given only the V1 item id?

Tags: square-connect

If I have a V1 catalog id, let's say for an item/variant, is there a way to retrieve the V2 catalog id for the item/variant? Let's say I get a webhook for a sale (which is V1 only, and I'm assuming will contain the V1 catalog id), how can I figure out which V2 item/variant the sale was for? This is specifically for processing POS transactions, as itemizations for those are not available in the V2 api.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way you would have to do this is to pull your entire v2 catalog and then look at the `catalog_v1_ids` to match them up. You could optimize this a bit with caching and or using the [Catalog Search Endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-searchcatalogobjects)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the search endpoint, that's very helpful!